# Which file format is suitable for unstructured data?

Tags: amazon-s3, data-lake, aws-data-pipeline

I am creating a data-repository more like creating data-lake for no-SQL db. I have some field which doesn't have a proper schema. They have mix type object like field value is {a:2} or {b:2,c:4, a: {1,2}}, etc.

I can use CSV format so I can save space/storage but due to unstructured/schema-less objects, I am going with the JSON file.

Is there any other way to store data??

I am using AWS S3 as storage for data-lake.